# Does F-string float formatting really violate PEP 8

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8

`a=3.1415`

`print(f"[{a:.2f}]")`

produces

`[3.14]`

that's OK, but PyCharm says: PEP 8: E231 missing whitespace after ':'

fixed version

`print(f"[{a: .2f}]")`

produces

`[ 3.14]`

which has extra space before the number.

Who's to blame: Python, Pycharm or me :-)

Comment: Seem pretty obvious that PEP 8 wasn't meant to apply inside string literals.  Perhaps PyCharm assumes that the content of the string is also Python code.  It does look like a dictionary inside a list but that's kind of a stretch (an oversight is more likely)

Comment: I have the same opinion and reported it to PyCharm support. Thank you.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-63374/E231-false-positive-in-f-strings-after-PEP-701-support